# Western digital external hard drive issue

Tags: external-hard-drive

When I plug in my WD external hard drive, it attempts to install (tried on multiple computers as well) and it install but it comes up with "WD HARDWARE ERROR USB Device", so it doesn't actually come up for me to do anything.

When searching through Google all I find are issues with the WD SES Device but that's not my issue.

Comment: Sounds like the drive (or it carrier) has a hardware error, at least judging by the error message, so it's time to replace it.  What's your question to us exactly?

Comment: Was to see if there was a fix for it or if it's just gone completely. It does show in diskmgmt.msc but it asks me to initialize it, I try to but it gives me "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error."

Comment: As a whole, it's dead. If you want to test the drive and/or chassis to see which is at fault, you'll have to take it apart, try the drive directly, and/or try a known-good drive in the chassis.

Comment: I figued as much, just thought i'd reach out and see if there was something I could do. Thanks.

Comment: Remove the drive from the enclosure and use a hard drive to usb adapter, connect it to the pc, if you can browse the drive now the enclosure is bad.

Comment: Try connecting it with a different USB cable. If that doesn't work you can scan the HDD with [WD DLG](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en). Could you also specify what model exactly is this HDD?

Answer (score 1):

"WD HARDWARE ERROR" is shown by the USB controller when it can't recognize the drive as a Western Digital.

To do so, the firmware of the enclosure looks from some SMART tables and drive identification.

If you, for example put a Seagate/Hitachi drive in the enclosure you will get the same error which is misleading because the drive is FINE.

You can anyway connect the drive to another enclosure and see if it's readable or what is the real problem.

You can also get rid of the Western Digital firmware and flash a generic firmware for that controller (asmedia or jmicron).

Answer (score 0):

The error definitely seems concerning, so I'd advise you to run the [WD's Data LifeGuard Diagnostics](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en) for Windows and check up on the health and SMART status of the drive.

Another thing you could try is to see if the error persists using a different USB cable or on another computer.

I'd also recommend you to check the drive's warranty on our website [here](http://support.wdc.com/Warranty/warrantyStatus.aspx?lang=en). If it's still covered, you could RMA it and get a replacement from us.